# Configurable Map Viewer Print Widget

Tags: arcgis-server, configurable-map-viewer

I want to print the map with operational layers, but it failed, i use cmv viewer, when i remove layers, printing works, is there a configuration which i must do in the server ?
Below is the part of widget's code

```
          print: {
            include: true,
            id: 'print',
            type: 'titlePane',
            canFloat: true,
            path: 'gis/dijit/Print',
            title: 'Imprimer la carte',
            open: false,
            position: 6,
            options: {
                map: true,
                printTaskURL: 'http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task',
                copyrightText: 'sarl',
                authorText: 'fedwa',
                defaultTitle: 'Entrez un titre ',
                defaultFormat: 'PDF',
                defaultLayout: 'Letter ANSI A Landscape'
            }
        },
```

here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Print issues related to certain layers almost certainly have to do with permissions of the ArcGIS Server Print Service NOT having access to the layers you want to print. You will need to troubleshoot this on the AGS server. Here's an article to get you started. http://communityhub.esriuk.com/technicalsupport/2014/10/24/troubleshooting-web-service-printing-failures.html